# Looking for a parser for QML-format files

Tags: qt, parsing, static-analysis, qml

I need to do some static analysis of [QML](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativeintroduction.html)-format files ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML)), but I can't find any parsers for them. The only way I see is to reuse source code of the [Qt Declarative](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtdeclarative.html) module or write my own parser. I can't find anything on the web. Can anyone point me to some tool, converter to XML or Perl/Python module to easily parse elements from QML files?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason to not use code from the QT Declarative module?  I'd avoid writing a parser, on the grounds that you are unlikely to know the precise grammar (unless it is hiding in the Qt sources somewhere).

Comment: It is one of the possible solutions, but my preferred languages are Perl and Python and I'll try to avoid writing a C++ code in my project. Also I don't want to depend on Qt in order to run the analysis on the servers that may not have it installed.

Comment: There is a grammar attached to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12602), though that grammar is missing whitespace information and semicolons-for-same-line-property-declarations, so it's not quite perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at the source code of the [QML Viewer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmlviewer.html) that comes with the SDK. The [source code](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.7/tools/qml) is available on Gitorious. QML Viewer code is in C++ not Python nor Perl.

Another possible solution, to use Python with no dependencies with Qt, is to use a standard Javascript parser and modify it so it can understand QML.  From the wiki link you provided :

> Because QML and JavaScript are very similar almost all code editors supporting JavaScript will do the job.

I found [pynarcissus](http://code.google.com/p/pynarcissus/) which is a Javascript interpreter in Python.  May be you could modify it slightly so it can interprete corretly QML files?

Comment: It is an excellent idea to use a JavaScript parser! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The parser in [qt-declarative](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative) is in src/qml/qml/parser, and a big part of it is generated with qlalr (same place as the previous link, but with qlalr instead of qtdeclarative).
You might want also to look at the parser used in [qt-creator](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator) src/libs/qmljs/parser which is derived from the qt-declarative one.